# Zip folder through unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a folder structure /home/testvis/Inbound/image

Inside image i have one file xx_test.csv and one folder Blobfile

I want to zip all the contents of image folder to image.zip

When i am using the following command :

```
zip -9 -r image.zip image
```

It is creating a zip file image.zip in the /home/testvis/Inbound location

When i extract this zip folder i can see that there are two folders
one with image and other with  /home/testvis/Inbound

I only want the image.zip to have contents of image-xx_test.csv and one folder Blobfile

Comment: see this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93139/can-i-zip-an-entire-folder-using-gzip

Comment: use zip -r image.zip image
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/zip-all-files-in-directory